# Inherited dependency property isn't recognized inside control template

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties, controltemplate

I have a `LabeledTextBox` with LabelText and LabelTextColor dependency properties. I have a `SearchTextBox`, which extends LabeledTextBox. When I put this in the control template of SearchTextBox:

```
<ui:LabeledTextBox x:Name="PART_LabeledTextBox" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5,0,0,0"
   LabelText="{TemplateBinding LabelText}" 
   LabelTextColor="{TemplateBinding LabelTextColor}" BorderBrush="Transparent" />
```

It gives me the `The member "LabelText" is not recognized or is not accessible.` error, and the same for LabelTextColor. However, if I simply set these things outside of the control template (which doesn't solve my problem), like this

```
<Setter Property="LabelText" Value="Test" />
<Setter Property="LabelTextColor" Value="Red" />
```

then it doesn't complain. What gives?

Comment: Is the `SearchTextBox` class derived from `LabeledTextBox`? If not, does it contain dependency properties named `LabelText` and `LabelTextColor`? *EDIT*: And did you set the `TargetType` property of the `ControlTemplate` to `SearchTextBox`?

Comment: Yes, it is derived from LabeledTextBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I forgot to define the type for the control template!

`<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ui:SearchTextBox}">`